# Is it safe to store raw meat alongside pre-cooked produce (ie. ready-made pies) in the fridge?

Tags: food-safety, meat, refrigerator, storage, raw

Simply, as the title says I’d like to know if it is safe to store raw meat alongside pre-cooked produce (ie. ready-made pies) in the fridge. Given the ready-made pies still need to be cooked to a high temperature – would this be considered safe?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Ideally, you'd store all meat tightly wrapped and/or in air-tight containers. Further, you'd store the meat on the bottom shelf of the fridge, and the ready-to-eat food above it—just in case the meat leaks juices out, it won't be able to drip onto the ready-to-eat foods. That's perfectly safe, and indeed is what's required in a commercial fridge.

The idea is to avoid any chance of cross-contamination. You don't want juice from the meat dripping or splashing (when you move it, for example) onto anything else.

You also want your pies tightly wrapped, to avoid them drying out or picking up off flavors.

Now, if cross-contamination were to occur, you'd want to use that pie quickly, and when reheating it, you need to make sure to bring its internal temperature—measured with a food thermometer in a few spots—up to 165°F/74°C (just like if you were cooking chicken). I suspect your normal pie reheating doesn't do that.

Answer (score 2):

You can keep it when you keep them separately in separate container. Try to arrange an airtight container otherwise the fridge will stink from the raw meat's smell.

Answer (score 1):

As long as there is no contact (each food is in its own container), you are fine.

Answer (score -2):

That's a no no.  Unless any item next to the meat is not cooked to 165-172 prior to eating you may end up with a belly ache.  That is why they invented Tupperware. Never store meats above produce and always make sure they are in a sealed container if you do not have that option.